# rule-based deletion

Tags: list-manipulation

[previous rule-based deletions from previous lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181162/list-management-deletion-of-duplicates#181172)

@Bill and @kglr have been very helpful and patient as I refine my issue.

Using the nomenclature of the previous question, we have:

```
lisA = {{Sat,"a",1,"b",2},{Sat,"c",3,"d",4},{Sat,"e",5,"f",6}}
```

and

```
lisB = {{"a",1,"b",2},{"c",3,"d",5},{"e",5,"f",6}}
```

Applying @kglr's solution, we get:

```
{{Sat,  a,  1,  b,  2},
 {Sat,  c,  3,  d,  4},
 {Sat,  e,  5,  f,  6},
 {c,    3,  d,  5}  
 {Sat,  c,  3,  d,  5}}
```

but the desired result is:

```
{{Sat,   a,  1,   b,  2},
 {Sat,   c,  3,   d,  4},
 {Sat,   c,  3,   d,  5},
 {Sat,   e,  5,   f,  6}}
```

Since all of the games in lisA take place on the same weekend date, that date gets prepended to the non-matching element from lisB.

Obviously I could simply delete cases where an element of res only has four elements...

Comment: Suite401, updated answer in the linked q/a gives `{{{x, x}, {y, y}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{e, f}, {g, h}}}` as desired.

Comment: I agree. Once again, thanks @ kglr and @Bill.  I am going to play around with this some more tomorrow and will let you know how it goes.